# Computing FOLLOW sets for LL(1) grammar. Stuck on question

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, parsers

> Calculate the FOLLOW sets for all the non terminals:
>
> $S \rightarrow bEx \mid Db \mid b \mid F$
>
> $D \rightarrow EDc \mid Y$
>
> $E \rightarrow dED \mid dDY$
>
> $Y \rightarrow ab \mid aDx \mid \varepsilon$

So I know that:

FOLLOW($S$) = $\{\$\}$ since it doesn't appear anywhere

FOLLOW($D$) = $\{b, a, x, c\}$, since it is followed by terminal $b$ in $S$, $c$ in $D$, FIRST($Y$) in $E$ which is $\{a\}$ ($\varepsilon$ not included), and $x$ in $Y$

FOLLOW($E$) = $\{x, c, a, d\}$, since it is followed by terminal $x$ in $S$, FIRST($D$) in $D$ which is $\{a, d, c\}$

but how do I calculate FOLLOW($Y$)? It isn't followed by anything. I'm guessing since it's at the end of $D$ and $E$ its the union of their follow sets including $\$$ since there's an $\varepsilon$?

Have been stuck on this for a while, any help is HIGHLY appreciated. Thanks in advance for any input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, the FOLLOW set of any non-terminal can be computed with the following rules (an example using these rules can be found [here](http://www.jambe.co.nz/UNI/FirstAndFollowSets.html)):

1. $\$$ (the end of input symbol) is in FOLLOW($S$) where $S$ is the start symbol.
2. If $A \rightarrow \alpha B\beta$, then everything in FIRST($\beta$) except $\varepsilon$ is in FOLLOW($B$).
3. If we have $A \rightarrow \alpha B\beta$ as before *and* $\varepsilon$ is in FIRST($\beta$), then all of FOLLOW($A$) is in FOLLOW($B$).
4. If $A \rightarrow \alpha B$, then all of FOLLOW($A$) is in FOLLOW($B$).

So for $Y$, we need to apply rule $4$ (as you correctly guessed), so FOLLOW($Y$) $=$ FOLLOW($D$) $\cup$ FOLLOW($E$) $= \{a,b,c,d,x\}$ (I'm trusting your working on the two follow sets).

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me but on my assignment 3 weeks ago with this question, for some reason I included $ in Follow(Y) and got full marks for it. So I probably calculated Follow(D) or Follow(E) wrong? :p

Comment: Or maybe it's because Y has EPISILON ?

Comment: @eyesenberg should the $S \rightarrow F$ rule actually be $S \rightarrow E$? This would put all of FOLLOW($S$) in FOLLOW($E$) and hence in FOLLOW($Y$).

Comment: Nevermind, spoke to other students and confirmed that her marking was wrong. Many thanks

Comment: @eyesenberg that's always a good way to get confused ;)

Answer (score 1):

> $FOLLOW\ (Y) = FOLLOW\ (D)$
>
> $FOLLOW\ (Y) = FOLLOW\ (E)$

A general Rule of thumb is, for any grammar

1. S -> XAB
2. A -> BC
3. X -> Bt

$
Follow (B) = Follow (S)  $
(Since there isn't anything after B in Production-1)

$Follow (B) = First (C) $ (Since C follows B in Production-2 and is a non-terminal)

$Follow (B) = t $ (since it follows B in Production-3 and is a terminal)

Comment: Thanks for this. Just for clarification, this also means that Follow(C) = Follow(A) (since there isn't anything after C in production A) right?

Comment: @eyesenberg **Absolutely**. It is a generic rule and is applied whenever there isn't anything after a Non-terminal in a Production. So `Follow(C) = Follow(A)`

Comment: @eyesenberg And if you think the answer helps you and can benefit others, you may choose to accept it !